# spark sql query in playframework shows empty result

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

When I run a `GroupBy` query in `spark-shell` it shows me perfect results but when I run the same query using spark SQL in `playframework` with the same spark version it shows me an empty result. I have a similar issue with join Operations. Cross join operations work in play framework with `sbt` but other joins show empty results.

I am using `spark 2.4.0`, `play framework 2.7` and `sbt 1.2.8`.

here is my code

```
var file_name1 ="excel1.xlsx" 
var file_name2 ="excel2.xlsx"       

var df1 =Spark.sqlContext.read
.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
.option("sheetName", "sheet1") // Required
.option("useHeader", "true") // Required
.option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false") 
.option("inferSchema", true) 
.option("addColorColumns", "false")
.option("timestampFormat", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
.load(file_name1)
.limit(10)
var df2 =Spark.sqlContext.read
.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
.option("sheetName", "sheet1") // Required
.option("useHeader", "true") // Required
.option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false") 
.option("inferSchema", true) // Optional, default: false
.option("addColorColumns", "false") // Optional, default: false
.option("timestampFormat", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss") // Optional, 
default: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
.load(file_name2)
.limit(10)

df1.registerTempTable("temp1")
df2.registerTempTable("temp2")
val df= sqlContext.sql("select * from temp1 inner join temp2 on 
temp1.a==temp2.a")
df.show()
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide the code?

Comment: Hi Oli thanks for your response, Please find my code.